# c++ Binary search through recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

I receive an error when the first recursice call is made, the error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x002A2E44 in rekBinSearch.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000A.

It is caused by:

> if ((*pEnd - *pBegin) == 0) /* There's only one element */

It seems that that when i set the new start- and end-adress, i do something wrong since these can't be read on the recursive call. They are "set" by:

> find(x, (int*)pBegin, pMid);

Full code:

```
    bool find(const int x, const int* pBegin, const int* pEnd)
{
   if ((*pEnd - *pBegin) == 0) /* There's only one element */
    {
        if (x == (int)pEnd)    /* That element could be the correct one */
            return true;
        else                   /* If it is not then return false, x is not in the array */
            return false;
    }

    int *pMid = (int*)(pEnd - pBegin);  /* pMid should be the adress to the element in the middle of the array */
    if (x >= (int)pMid)                 /* If x is in array it is to the right of the middle */
        find(x, (int*)pMid, pEnd);  
    else                                /* If x is in array it is to the left of the middle */           
        find(x, (int*)pBegin, pMid);

}// find
```

What am I doing wrong or how am I thinking wrong?

Comment: Get rid of all those casts and you'll be half-way to solving the problem,  I suspect.

Comment: `(pEnd - pBegin)` doesn't compute a midpoint, but the number of elements between the pointers. Perhaps there are 0x0A elements?

Comment: The idiomatic use of an iterator like syntax is to treat equality of the beginning and ending to indicate an empty interval.  Your function does not detect being passed an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong or how am I thinking wrong?

**Problem 1**

You are confusing between pointers and values. Examples:

```
if ((*pEnd - *pBegin) == 0) /* There's only one element */
```

and

```
if (x == (int)pEnd)
```

`int(pEnd)` does not get the value of the object that `pEnd` points to. It just treats the pointer value as an `int`.

**Problem 2**

Also, you are not returning properly from the recursive calls.

```
    find(x, (int*)pMid, pEnd);  // Missing return
```

and

```
    find(x, (int*)pBegin, pMid); // Missing return
```

**Fixed up function**

Here's a version that should work.

```
bool find(const int x, const int* pBegin, const int* pEnd)
{
   if ((pEnd - pBegin) == 0) /* There's only one element */
   {
      return (x == *pEnd);  /* That element could be the correct one */
                            /* If it is not then return false, x is not in the array */
   }

   int midIndex = (pEnd - pBegin)/2;
   int const* pMid = pBegin + midIndex; /* pMid should be the adress to the element in the middle of the array */
   if (x >= *pMid)                     /* If x is in array it is to the right of the middle */
      return find(x, pMid, pEnd);  
   else                                /* If x is in array it is to the left of the middle */           
      return find(x, pBegin, pMid-1);

}// find
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful to OP to reiterate that `(int)pEnd` does not return the `int` value pointed to by `pEnd`. In order to get the value of a pointer, you use (as you've correctly done in your fixed function) `*pEnd`.

Comment: @R-Sahu I missed to give feedback, sorry. This helped a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want `if ((pEnd - pBegin) == 0)`? Notice that there is no dereference pointers. Dereferencing  pend is always a bad idea since it doesn't point to anything.